# Share Button on ActionBar Appears Twice

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-sharing

I've created a share button on my Action Bar - but it seems to appear twice.

[image]

The menu `XML` file is below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"   
    />

</menu>
```

And it is instantiated in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` in the view.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

    mShareActionProvider =
            (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

    if(mShareActionProvider != null && !mForecastString.isEmpty()){
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
    } else{
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Share Action provider is null?");
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

How could the share button appear twice if it is defined, inflated, and instantiated only once?

Comment: Really it's very strange. Never seen before.

Comment: You may have used the same `onCreateOptionsMenu` in base activity class and its extension, or in activity and a fragment.

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what the problem was!

Comment: I guess, You are inflating Menu twice. 1st from Activity and 2nd from fragment. - you need to remove from any one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are inflating Menu twice, both in the  Activity and the Fragment.

Removing one inflation should fix the problem.

Comment: I am agree with this.

Answer (score 3):

Just before inflating menu options use menu.clear();

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
     menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

    mShareActionProvider =
            (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

    if(mShareActionProvider != null && !mForecastString.isEmpty()){
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
    } else{
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Share Action provider is null?");
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to repetitive inflation of menu. 
 use menu.clear() before inflation.

```
    @Override 
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
     menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu_layout, menu);
 }
```